# IOKit in iOS10 beta

Tags: ios, ios10, iokit

I used the IOKit api to retrieve the raw data of an iOS device's battery. When I updated my iPhone to the iOS 10 beta, I found it doesn't work properly. Only the voltage of battery can be shown and other data like maxCapacity, cycleCount were absent.

I found there was more data absent when I used the IOKit Browser. I think Apple has made a great amendment on IOKit in iOS 10, and less data can be retrieved.  Does that mean we cannot use IOKit in iOS 10 as we did in the early version iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Yep.
Afaik tons of IOKit functions have restrictions now in iOS10.

Too bad you can't use IOKit to obtain user's uniqueID and leak their privacy now, Oooops. Also, no more advertisement walls. Oooooooops